# On screen rotation, activity onCreate() is not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

I have an activity and an attached fragment to it. Here is my activity code:

```
public class GeneralSettingActivity extends BasePreferenceActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.redesign_general_prefs);
        Log.e("Sushil", "...RedesignGeneralSettingsActivity onCreate()....");

        initGeneralSettingsFragment(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private void initGeneralSettingsFragment(Bundle bundle) {
        if (bundle == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragments_container, mGeneralSettingsFragment = new GeneralSettingsFragment(), ALARM_GENERAL_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        } else {
            mGeneralSettingsFragment = (GeneralSettingsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ALARM_GENERAL_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    }
----
----
```

and here is my fragment code:

```
public class GeneralSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    private GeneralSettingActivity mParentActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mParentActivity = (GeneralSettingActivity)getActivity();

        (!mParentActivity.mPrefs.contains(SharedPreferencesWrapper.GeneralSettingKeys.CLOCK_24_HOURS))

------
------
```

When I rotate the screen, my fragment onCreate is called but my activity onCreate is not called again. For the activity, I have not done any setting in manifest file to stop the activity from getting destroyed.

Can someone help me to find out why my activity onCreate is not called. My activity eventually extends from AppCompatActivity.

Thanks for any help

Comment: you should take a look and onResume please read this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: @PedroAGSantos.. thnaks for your reply. In my case, I am rotating the screen, so as per the article you shared, it should be called again..

Comment: how are you verify that it's not recreating the activity? Debugging ?

Comment: @PedroAGSantos.. I have logs in onCreate of both of them. The thing is that I have a variable mPrefs in parentactivity which i use in fragment. I initialize it in onCreate of parent. But, I see that on rotation it is null as patent onCreate was not called before fragment onCreate

Comment: @Sushil instead of calling `getActivity()` in the fragments onCreate maybe call it in the `onAttach()`. I am not sure if that will solve your problem but may help a little.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".GeneralSettingActivity "
          android:configChanges="orientation">
```

And calling the onConfigurationChanged in your activity to handle the rotation event

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is considered bad design to handle orientation changes by yourself unless their is some specific scenario to do so. I don't have a specific requirement to do so. Thanks for your answer anyways

Answer (score 1):

Adding  android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" to the activity will trigger onCreate needs to be called.